# In PHPExcel i merger three cell and having foreach loop. Result next value not printed after merge

Tags: php, joomla, phpexcel

$periodOne=array(array('SNO','Appraisal','TOT','AVG','CLS TOT','CLS AVG','DIFF'));

```
    $rowID = 7;
    foreach($periodOne as $rowArray) {
       $columnID = 'A';
       foreach($rowArray as $columnValue) {

            $this->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('B7:D7');
            $this->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columnID.$rowID,$columnValue);



           $columnID++;     


       }
       $rowID++;
    }
```

Comment: Besides the fact that you're merging B7:D7 multiple times; you're also then trying too get cells C7 and D7 (which no longer exist because they're merged into B7)

Comment: and solution for that

Comment: I got it.. but its little tricky, the if else situation help me.

Comment: One solution: move the merge __before__ the foreach loop, and add a couple of dummy null values into your array in place of columns C and D

Comment: An alternative would be to make your `$periodOne` array associative by column `('A' => 'NO', 'B' => 'Appraisal', 'E' => 'TOT', 'F' => 'AVG', etc)` and use that column reference in your setCellValue instead of `$columnID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$periodOne=array(array('SNO','Appraisal','TOT','AVG','CLS TOT','CLS AVG','DIFF'));      

    $rowID = 7;
    foreach($periodOne as $rowArray) {
       $columnID = 'A';
       foreach($rowArray as $columnValue) {
        if($columnID.$rowID == 'C7')
        {
            $columnID = 'E';



            $this->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columnID.$rowID,$columnValue);



        }
        else
        {   

            $this->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columnID.$rowID,$columnValue);


         }      
         $columnID++;

       }
       $rowID++;
    }
```